# Paragraph Style Selector CSS different ways - Design Consideration

Tags: css, html

Two different paragraph can be given two different type of colours using the below css code.

```
.paraStyle1{
 color: rgb(100,100,100);
}

.paraStyle2{
 color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

Now, In the html code i can Specify

```
<p class="paraStyle1">Hello</p>
<p class="paraStyle2">Hello There</p>
```

The above CSS code can be modified to as Shown below, So which one should be used, considering best coding Technique(Design).

```
p.paraStyle1{
 color: rgb(100,100,100);
}

p.paraStyle2{
 color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

Comment: Since both ways have the same effect in the simple case given, any preference is based either on opinions or on considerations of issues that were not mentioned in the question (such as the possible effects of selector specificity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes can be duplicated which means a `p` tag and a `div` tag can have same class.

But if you want to style only the `p` tag then you should follow the second style. If you are not using your class anywhere else except for the `p` tag you can use the first style.

Answer (score 1):

```
.paraStyle1{
 color: rgb(100,100,100);
}

.paraStyle2{
 color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

will not be limited to `p` tags....it can be allocated to any tag having the class `paraStyle1` or `paraStyle2`, it can be `a`,`p` or even a div... [**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKLUW/)

```
p.paraStyle1{
 color: rgb(100,100,100);
}

p.paraStyle2{
 color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

is specifically for the `p` tags having classes `paraStyle1` or `paraStyle2`....no other html tag can avail the style of these classes except `p` tags.... [**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKLUW/1/) !!

Answer (score 0):

The second syntax (`p.paraStyle1`) applies the contained css only to p tags with the paraStyle1 class. You should use this syntax if you are planning on reusing that class name with different styling for different tags.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify your CSS selector to be `p.<class>`, it means that you only want the **p tags** with that class to be styled. However, if you need this same style to be applied to other tags as well (eg a `<div>` tag), then use the first method.